# Is it possible to play New Leaf on multiple systems with a cartridge?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

If my brother and I each have a 3DS or if someone has multiple systems, is it possible to play it on both systems, assuming you have a physical cartridge of the game?

Comment: Do you mean play together or just, will the game work from one 3DS to another? I'm a little unsure what you're asking. Like, are you asking if you can have multiple save files?

Comment: @Zorpix: Either way. Either having a save on each 3DS or just playing in the same town on multiple systems.

Comment: Well there is no download play, so you would need two cartridges to play together. What me and my girlfriend do is share a cartridge, I'm the mayor of the town, and she has her own save file that lets her be a resident in my town.

Comment: @Zorpix: That's what I'm asking, if it's possible to share a single game card.

Comment: with that information, I posted an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It is possible for you both to play on one game card. However, the game saves to the cartridge, not the actual system itself. Therefore, you will have to share the same town. The only problem is that one of you will be the mayor, and the other will be a resident in the town. It doesnt affect much except your ability to create public works projects and create ordinances, really something the two of you can discuss in person and work out in the real world. Other than that, the game will be almost identical, except for some of the villagers not calling you the mayor.

[Here's a discussion on the official Nintendo forums about using the same cartridge on multiple 3DS systems.](http://techforums.nintendo.com/thread/8683)

Have fun!

Comment: I added a link to the official Nintendo forum. Although no moderator took part in the discussion, this should be credible enough a source for the bounty, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible since the game data is stored in the cartridge itself, but Nintendo has made an application available on eShop that allows you to transfer game data into SD Card. So you can use the same cartridge on different systems, but with different game data. Or, you can leave the game data on the cartridge and play, but one of you guys will gonna be a mayor, while the other will not.

Comment: If so, that's cool. Have you tried this? Does the backed up data still work with the game card fine? I thought that was mostly just a backup tool. I also thought that I heard something about it storing a key of the last play on both the system and the game card to prevent cheating, but I wasn't sure how it worked.

Comment: @Ullallulloo As far as I know you can only transfer cartridge save data to a 3DS for use with a digital copy of the game. The transfer is one-way only and does not work the other way around, so it's **not** a backup and thus the transferred savegame **does not** work with the cartridge version of the game. It should be explained somewhere on the 3DS e-shop.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you guys can play on the same game cartridge but have different save files.